# Prevent BitBucket from deploying to heroku when pushed to develop

Tags: javascript, git, heroku, bitbucket

I've set up bitbucket to automatically deploy to Heroku by setting up a bitbucket-pipelines.yml file. The code for that file is included below. Everything is working great. I've got every time I deploy, Heroku picks it up and builds successfully. However, it's happening on both branches. I prefer to only build after a master branch commit. I assume this is possible but solutions I've found don't seem to work.

**bitbucket-pipelines.yml file:**

```
image: node:6.9.4

  pipelines:
    default:
      - step:
          caches:
            - node
          script:
            - npm install
            - git push https://heroku:$HEROKU_API_KEY@git.heroku.com/$HEROKU_APP_NAME.git HEAD
```

**Solutions I've tried:** (will update as I continue to research)

- added ':refs/heads/master' behind 'HEAD' on the final line of bitbucket.pipelines.yml

EDIT: 
Per VonC's suggestion, I changed my bitbucket-pipelines.yml file to the code below and it works! Thank you so much for your assistance.

```
image: node:6.9.4

  pipelines:
    branches:
      master:
        - step:
            caches:
              - node
            script:
              - npm install
              - git push https://heroku:$HEROKU_API_KEY@git.heroku.com/$HEROKU_APP_NAME.git HEAD
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should be what the "[Branch workflows](https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucket/branch-workflows-856697482.html)" describes:

```
image: node:5.11.0
pipelines:
  default:
    - step:
        script:
          - echo "This script runs on all branches that don't have any specific pipeline assigned in 'branches'."
  branches:
    master:
      - step:
          script:
            - echo "This script runs only on commit to the master branch."
    feature/*:
      - step:
          image: java:openjdk-9 # This step uses its own image
          script:
            - echo "This script runs only on commit to branches with names that match the feature/* pattern."
```